# [React-Native][IOS]How to dynamic set Debug server host for device setting like Android

Tags: ios, react-native

> My mac-os using Wifi and when i move to other place my ip change and i
>   always rebuild app for testing. Rebuild app is annoying.

- How can i set Development Server IP Address in IOS after build and run on Physical Device?

on Android, i can set Development Server in `Dev Menu, Dev Settings, Debug server host for device setting` but nowhere found in IOS.

Comment: I have exactly this problem. I can't understand why this option is not available in ios. At first I thought it's just missed on simulator, but then realized there is no difference between simulated or physical device!

Answer (score 1):

Why couldn't you have a `UIViewController` with a `UITextField` that contains the URL or IP you want to use and a `UIButton` on it that saves and updates this, then store the result in `UserDefaults` and pull from that for a URL every time?

There are also other options like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/), which I would use instead of the above if you have many variables you'd want to configure on the fly like this.

If you're just trying to swap the IP/port as you move to a new network, I'd still just store it in `UserDefaults` and make a page to update it, though.

Comment: I jump to React Native without knowledge Native IOS or Android. I can set Development Server IP Address (in Developer Menu) in Android without re-build. But in Developer Menu of IOS don't have that useful option

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool to solve the problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

```
http-server -p 8081 -P Http://{host}:{port}
```

and use Xcode run app project.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  The question is how to change the native app's bundle url dynamically at runtime, not how to host the packager

Comment: I dont wanna re-build and re-install App on physical device

Answer (score 0):

Install react-native-DebugServerHost, link it and run again:

```
npm install react-native-DebugServerHost --save

react-native link

react-native run-ios
```

Then new option will be appear in Developer Menu. After setting the ip of dev server you have to kill the app and run it again.

--

**Pod integration**

```
npm install react-native-DebugServerHost --save
```

podFile file added:

```
pod 'DebugServerHost', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-DebugServerHost'

pod install
```

**Manual integration:**

Simply add the DebugServerHost folder to your project without any settings.

Repository:
https://github.com/xuwening/react-native-debug-server-host